# How to specify local save path for database file in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I am making an app using **Pymongo (MongoDB)**. I have managed to work my way around logging the data to a MongoDB database, but I want to be able to specify the **exact path** where database file would be saved.

The reason why I want this is the fact that another app should be able to *select* (this is really important) the db file and load it's content. And it needs to be easy to find that specific file.

**EDIT**:
Editing the configuration file of Mongo is not an option for me because this should be possible for the user to specify every time the program is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `cant` do that in python.

you must go to mongodb `settings` on your machine and tell where to save your databases

pymongo its just a client to communicate with the `mongodb` server.

but, you can specify to which database to connect to using `pymongo`, like this:

```
MONGO_URI_db1 = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost:27017/database1"
MONGO_URI_db2 = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost:27017/database2"
```

to edit the database location for mongodb there is this [inspiration](https://askubuntu.com/a/257724/1194012) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Can u take a look at the edit of the question? And also, is there a possibility to do this in other NoSQL technology? i.e. it doesn't have to be Mongo.
So a certain directory should contain multiple db files, and the directory is specified by the user of the app

Comment: then create multiple databases and specifiy then using mongo uri in python

Comment: i know what are you talking about, but you need to understand that mongo and every other db has a cluster on your system or a server with multiple databases inside, which is called `db cluster`

Comment: That was my first thought,  but it doesn't give me control over the directory where each of them should be saved. In this app you can have several directories with several db files. And that is why I have asked if there is another NoSQL option.

Comment: every other nosql or sql db works like this, the cluster principle.

Comment: you can run multiple mongo servers, every each one with its folder

Comment: but `i dont think this is recommended`